# Listen any changes event on table HTML by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make `Total` field in HTML table always listen if any changes on Qty/Price/Disc field (see below). So Total field always updated.

```
Id | Product | Qty | Price | Disc | Total
1  |    A    |  1  |   2   |  0   |   2
2  |    B    |  2  |  10   |  10  |  18
...
```

Here's the HTML : http://jsfiddle.net/ao6t2axs/

How to do this using javascript/jQuery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are the fields being updated? Are they inputs or are they being updated by some other JS?

Comment: please show your code, what you are asking is relativly simple, but without seeing your code people can only guess. how is the table built? what is the element holding those values? how is Qty/Price etc updated?

Comment: Now, I am using other JS (x-editable), at least i want to know if we use HTML inputs to update the fields. @AndyNewman

Comment: now, i start coding with detect any changes in every field (Qty, Price, Disc)  @atmd

Comment: "i start coding with detect any changes in every field" what are 'fields'? `td`? `td`? `div`? `input`? show your html and js and you'll get much more informed answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have updated your jsfiddle with a working solution

http://jsfiddle.net/5bym3jq5/

Code is

```
$('#table').on('change', 'input', function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var total = 0;
    $('input', row).each(function() {
        total += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('.total', row).text(total);
});
```

Basically watch for any time an input inside the table fires a `change` event, find the row that that input is a part of, then update the total value for that row.

Comment: thanks for the code, just change little bit here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrefadila/db9cjy7y/